# What is the meaning of "Do not execute a remote command"?

Tags: ssh

In the man page of ssh, it says:

```
-N    Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.
```

I don't understand what it means by "Do not execute a remote command."

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 27):

Normally, the `ssh` program runs a command on a remote system (using the remote user's shell). For example, `ssh user@server ls -l /tmp` lists the content of the /tmp directory on `server`. When you leave the command out, as in `ssh user@server`, an interactive login session with the user's shell is launched.

One of the features of OpenSSH is the creation of tunnels. The `-D`, `-L` and `-R` options use various techniques that allow the forwarding of network ports, also known as tunneling. By default, a tunnel created with `ssh` exists as long as the command executed by `ssh` runs on the remote server.

Often though, you are not interested in running a remote command; all you want is the tunnel. This is what the `-N` option is for.

Comment: There is at least one situation where you want to run a remote command, even though you only intend to use the tunnel: Often, in a cloud environment, your only access to the systems is by first logging in to a bastion server, and a common security feature is for the server to drop a session that appears passive, meaning your tunnel disappears. In that situation I usually run something like `ping localhost` as the remote command; this generates enough activity for the session to stay open.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n : there are other ways that do not necessarily necessitate a remote command, and that you can try to use instead of a "ping" : see common openssh option: TCPKeepAlive (that just sends a tcp packet every few seconds to keep the connection alive)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n seems like a bug in your bastion server

Comment: @OlivierDulac I've tried that one - it makes no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @user253751 That's what I keep telling them, but they assure me it isn't :-)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n : with the -N as well? (as if you don"t use -N : it opens a remote shell, that may have for exemple a TMOUT variable set (and often made readonly) [or other variable name, depending on the shell] ?)

Answer (score 13):

Usually, `ssh` will give you a remote shell by executing what is set up as your remote users login shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`). `-N` will prevent running anything, which is useful when you just want to use `ssh` to establish a connection and you don't need a remote shell.

e.g. forwarding ports or creating tunnels:

```bsh
ssh -N -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 user@server
```

---

And this is not only useful for forwarding ports.

E.g.: I use it in combination with `-f` and `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options (e.g. set up in .ssh/config), it can be used to create reusable connections.

```bsh
ssh -fN user@server # creates connection in the background that can be reused.
```